# How To Hide Elements in Visual Basic Designer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, designer

I am making a calculator/converter in Visual Ultimate 2012 (VB.NET). A user selects what type of conversion he wants to do and then the appropriate labels/text boxes appear (they are hidden until then), if the user selects another type other labels/text boxes appear on the same place, but the previous ones are hidden.

The problem is that in the designer (Form1.vb[Design]) I can't hide the labels/text boxes, to put other labels/text boxes in the same place.

**How can I hide elements (labels, text boxes, etc) in the designer in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012?**

Comment: You can't. That's where WPF comes in. You can hide things in the designer

Comment: You can, it requires a custom designer.  But you are solving the wrong problem, there's no point in having this happen at design time.  Make it happen at runtime.  Create panels at design time and set their Enabled property at runtime to display the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

i think you don't need to hide you just set location of to control same and use bring to front or send to back command